# getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream method returns null for a file with ".LIB" extension

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to load a file from resources/ path using

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.LIB")
```

but the method always returns null, unless I rename the file into another extension, say ".dll".

I've looked into the official Java documentation, but to no avail.

Why does the method acts strange on that file type?

Note: I'm using JDK 1.8.0_111 x86 (due to constraints on that lib file, which only works well with a 32-bit JVM)

Comment: You are sure this file is in your class path? BTW when you open a file this way, there is no reason to use 32-bit or 64-bit JVM, It only matters when loading shared libraries.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure since when the file is renamed in the same path, it gets loaded. Also, I've got other dll's which require 32-bit jvm (a shared library for using Prolog). That lib is one of their dependencies

Comment: If a DLL needs another file, you don't need to be reading it using the class path, which is NOT the path the DLL will use to load it.

Comment: I've got a dll and a bunch of files which need to be on the my classpath in order to load a library using System.loadLibrary.
So on startup I load those from the project's resource folder and copy them to the relevant path, instead of forcing the user to do it manually / writing a setup script.
But that has nothing to do with my question. Why does the classloader does not handle .lib file extensions well, also without any exception?

Comment: shared libraries use the PATH not the class path.

Comment: If you try to traverse all the locations in the current classpath as shown here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/ you'll see that the project path is included. Bottom line - it works, and I can prove it. However, that's not my question!

Comment: if it doesn't make sense it os probably working for the wrong reason such as multiple copies of the file you can find.

Comment: I've already said that your statement is wrong. System.loadLibrary also looks up in the project directory, (It traverses that + PATH directories). You can easily verify that. Also, removing the shared libraries from the project path makes the method fail since it can find them, so no duplicates. It is also for a fact that the main .dll works when its other dependencies are within the same path (it is an old dll, and cannot be replaced). And for the 3rd time - Why are you staying away from the core question? Regardless of that, try to load a .lib file as stream and see that it does not work!

Comment: yes. That is exactly what I said it uses the PATH environment variable to search for shared library resources. However the class loader doesnt use this PATH, it uses the class path which you specify on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

It does works for me, you need to be sure what exactly you are doing with lib file.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class FileHelper {

public String getFilePathToSave() {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    String filePath = "";

    try {

      InputStream inputStream =
        getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("abc.lib");

      prop.load(inputStream);
      filePath = prop.getProperty("json.filepath");

    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return filePath;

  }
public static void main(String args[]) {
  FileHelper fh = new FileHelper();
   System.out.println(fh.getFilePathToSave());

 }
}
```